# Wide to long (longitudinal) data transformation in R

Tags: r, dataset, transformation, reshape

I am wondering if you can help me transform my data to a longitudinal format.
I have a dataset as following (20 variables):

```
ptno    E0sex   calpcvd calcvdea    calrxgp age.baseline    age.year1   age.year2   age.year3   age.year4   age.year5   age.year6   Baseline    year1   year2   year3   year4   year5   year6   duration1
10021001    1   0   0   1   81.3744 82.3744 83.3744 84.3744 85.3744 86.3744 87.3744 0.66    0.68    0.64    0.64    0.38    8   8   6.5
10021002    1   0   0   2   81.18822    82.18822    83.18822    84.18822    85.18822    86.18822    87.18822    0.64    9   9   9   9   9   9   0.989041096
10021003    1   0   0   1   80.32307    81.32307    82.32307    83.32307    84.32307    85.32307    86.32307    0.63    8   9   9   9   9   9   1.21369863
10021004    1   0   0   1   87.00343    88.00343    89.00343    90.00343    91.00343    92.00343    93.00343    0.72    8   9   9   9   9   9   1.347945205
10021005    1   0   0   2   82.42026    83.42026    84.42026    85.42026    86.42026    87.42026    88.42026    0.74    8   8   8   8   8   9   5.052054795
10021006    1   0   0   2   81.54962    82.54962    83.54962    84.54962    85.54962    86.54962    87.54962    0.59    8   8   8   8   9   9   4.208219178
```

And I want to rearrange this such as (ages all combined as "age" and Baseline, year1... combined as utility:

```
id  obs E0sex   calpcvd calcvdea    calrxgp age utility duration
10021001    1   1   0   0   1   81.3744 0.66    6.5
10021001    2   1   0   0   1   82.3744 0.68    6.5
10021001    3   1   0   0   1   83.3744 0.64    6.5
10021001    4   1   0   0   1   84.3744 0.64    6.5
10021001    5   1   0   0   1   85.3744 0.38    6.5
10021001    6   1   0   0   1   86.3744 8   6.5
10021001    7   1   0   0   1   87.3744 8   6.5
10021002    1   1   0   0   2   81.18822    0.64    0.989041096
10021002    2   1   0   0   2   82.18822    9   0.989041096
10021002    3   1   0   0   2   83.18822    9   0.989041096
10021002    4   1   0   0   2   84.18822    9   0.989041096
10021002    5   1   0   0   2   85.18822    9   0.989041096
10021002    6   1   0   0   2   86.18822    9   0.989041096
10021002    7   1   0   0   2   87.18822    9   0.989041096
```

What would be the best way to do so?

Comment: use `reshape`from base R or `reshape2` from plyr package

Comment: @Metrics `reshape2` *is* a package, albeit from the same author and somewhat related to plyr. The function is called `melt`, with inverse `dcast`.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your data is sample:

```
dput(sample)
structure(list(ptno = 10021001:10021006, E0sex = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), calpcvd = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), calcvdea = c(0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), calrxgp = c(1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L), age.baseline = c(81.3744, 
81.18822, 80.32307, 87.00343, 82.42026, 81.54962), age.year1 = c(82.3744, 
82.18822, 81.32307, 88.00343, 83.42026, 82.54962), age.year2 = c(83.3744, 
83.18822, 82.32307, 89.00343, 84.42026, 83.54962), age.year3 = c(84.3744, 
84.18822, 83.32307, 90.00343, 85.42026, 84.54962), age.year4 = c(85.3744, 
85.18822, 84.32307, 91.00343, 86.42026, 85.54962), age.year5 = c(86.3744, 
86.18822, 85.32307, 92.00343, 87.42026, 86.54962), age.year6 = c(87.3744, 
87.18822, 86.32307, 93.00343, 88.42026, 87.54962), Baseline = c(0.66, 
0.64, 0.63, 0.72, 0.74, 0.59), year1 = c(0.68, 9, 8, 8, 8, 8), 
    year2 = c(0.64, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8), year3 = c(0.64, 9, 9, 9, 
    8, 8), year4 = c(0.38, 9, 9, 9, 8, 8), year5 = c(8L, 9L, 
    9L, 9L, 8L, 9L), year6 = c(8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L), duration1 = c(6.5, 
    0.989041096, 1.21369863, 1.347945205, 5.052054795, 4.208219178
    )), .Names = c("ptno", "E0sex", "calpcvd", "calcvdea", "calrxgp", 
"age.baseline", "age.year1", "age.year2", "age.year3", "age.year4", 
"age.year5", "age.year6", "Baseline", "year1", "year2", "year3", 
"year4", "year5", "year6", "duration1"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

b<-reshape(sample,direction='long',varying=list(c(6,7,8,9,10,11,12),c(13,14,15,16,17,18,19)),v.names=c("age","utility"))



 > b
        ptno E0sex calpcvd calcvdea calrxgp duration1 time      age utility id
1.1 10021001     1       0        0       1 6.5000000    1 81.37440    0.66  1
2.1 10021002     1       0        0       2 0.9890411    1 81.18822    0.64  2
3.1 10021003     1       0        0       1 1.2136986    1 80.32307    0.63  3
4.1 10021004     1       0        0       1 1.3479452    1 87.00343    0.72  4
5.1 10021005     1       0        0       2 5.0520548    1 82.42026    0.74  5
6.1 10021006     1       0        0       2 4.2082192    1 81.54962    0.59  6
1.2 10021001     1       0        0       1 6.5000000    2 82.37440    0.68  1
2.2 10021002     1       0        0       2 0.9890411    2 82.18822    9.00  2
3.2 10021003     1       0        0       1 1.2136986    2 81.32307    8.00  3
4.2 10021004     1       0        0       1 1.3479452    2 88.00343    8.00  4
5.2 10021005     1       0        0       2 5.0520548    2 83.42026    8.00  5
6.2 10021006     1       0        0       2 4.2082192    2 82.54962    8.00  6
1.3 10021001     1       0        0       1 6.5000000    3 83.37440    0.64  1
2.3 10021002     1       0        0       2 0.9890411    3 83.18822    9.00  2
3.3 10021003     1       0        0       1 1.2136986    3 82.32307    9.00  3
4.3 10021004     1       0        0       1 1.3479452    3 89.00343    9.00  4
5.3 10021005     1       0        0       2 5.0520548    3 84.42026    8.00  5
6.3 10021006     1       0        0       2 4.2082192    3 83.54962    8.00  6
1.4 10021001     1       0        0       1 6.5000000    4 84.37440    0.64  1
2.4 10021002     1       0        0       2 0.9890411    4 84.18822    9.00  2
3.4 10021003     1       0        0       1 1.2136986    4 83.32307    9.00  3
4.4 10021004     1       0        0       1 1.3479452    4 90.00343    9.00  4
5.4 10021005     1       0        0       2 5.0520548    4 85.42026    8.00  5
6.4 10021006     1       0        0       2 4.2082192    4 84.54962    8.00  6
1.5 10021001     1       0        0       1 6.5000000    5 85.37440    0.38  1
2.5 10021002     1       0        0       2 0.9890411    5 85.18822    9.00  2
3.5 10021003     1       0        0       1 1.2136986    5 84.32307    9.00  3
4.5 10021004     1       0        0       1 1.3479452    5 91.00343    9.00  4
5.5 10021005     1       0        0       2 5.0520548    5 86.42026    8.00  5
6.5 10021006     1       0        0       2 4.2082192    5 85.54962    8.00  6
1.6 10021001     1       0        0       1 6.5000000    6 86.37440    8.00  1
2.6 10021002     1       0        0       2 0.9890411    6 86.18822    9.00  2
3.6 10021003     1       0        0       1 1.2136986    6 85.32307    9.00  3
4.6 10021004     1       0        0       1 1.3479452    6 92.00343    9.00  4
5.6 10021005     1       0        0       2 5.0520548    6 87.42026    8.00  5
6.6 10021006     1       0        0       2 4.2082192    6 86.54962    9.00  6
1.7 10021001     1       0        0       1 6.5000000    7 87.37440    8.00  1
2.7 10021002     1       0        0       2 0.9890411    7 87.18822    9.00  2
3.7 10021003     1       0        0       1 1.2136986    7 86.32307    9.00  3
4.7 10021004     1       0        0       1 1.3479452    7 93.00343    9.00  4
5.7 10021005     1       0        0       2 5.0520548    7 88.42026    9.00  5
6.7 10021006     1       0        0       2 4.2082192    7 87.54962    9.00  6
```